# FCM Push Notification doesn't appear when app is in foreground - react native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

In react native app on Android everything is working perfectly when i run my app on debug mode, foreground and background both push notification are received fine without any error. But when I generate signed APK file only background pushes received and foreground pushes are not receiving.

I checked android debugging (Logcat) and I can see that notifications are receiving fine from Firebase and not show on foreground.

Here is my app.js code and this code are working.

```
// Firebase Cloud Messages Start
async componentDidMount() {
const notificationOpen: NotificationOpen = await firebase
    .notifications()
    .getInitialNotification();
if (notificationOpen) {
    const action = notificationOpen.action;
    const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
    var seen = [];
    alert(
        JSON.stringify(notification.data, function(key, val) {
            if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
                if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
                    return;
                }
                seen.push(val);
            }
            return val;
        })
    );
}
const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
    "test-channel",
    "Test Channel",
    firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max
).setDescription("My apps test channel");
// Create the channel
firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase
    .notifications()
    .onNotificationDisplayed((notification: Notification) => {
        // Process your notification as required
        // ANDROID: Remote notifications do not contain the channel ID. You will have to specify this manually if you'd like to re-display the notification.
    });    this.notificationListener = firebase
    .notifications()
    .onNotification((notification: Notification) => {
        // Process your notification as required
        notification.android
            .setChannelId("test-channel")
            .android.setSmallIcon("ic_launcher");
        firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification);
    });
this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase
    .notifications()
    .onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
        // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
        const action = notificationOpen.action;
        // Get information about the notification that was opened
        const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
        var seen = [];
        alert(
            JSON.stringify(notification.data, function(key, val) {
                if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
                    if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    seen.push(val);
                }
                return val;
            })
        );
        firebase
            .notifications()
            .removeDeliveredNotification(notification.notificationId);
    });}
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.notificationDisplayedListener();
        this.notificationListener();
        this.notificationOpenedListener();
    }
    // END
```

Also I am receiving these two errors :

```
Could not find class ‘android.app.NotificationChannelGroup’, referenced from method io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationManager.parseChannelGroupMap
Could not find class ‘android.app.NotificationChannel’, referenced from method io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationManager.parseChannelMap
```

Comment: Hi are you testing on Android O or higher devices? if yes then you have to create a notification channel for your notification to show.

Comment: I have tested this code on Android 4.4 and 8.0 and havent receives notifications. But this code is working fine on debugging mode on both devices.

Comment: are you sending the message notification in notification or data object?

Comment: Sorry I didnt get your point, I am sending push messages from Firebase console.

Comment: are you sending the  in this format "data": {
    "title": "I'd tell you a chemistry joke",
    "message": "but I know I wouldn't get a reaction",
    "image-url":
      "https://docs.centroida.co/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/notification.png"
  }

Comment: Here is the Logcat maybe this can help you to understand the issue cause.

Comment: Logging event(FE): notification_receive(_nr), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o) = fcm,firebase_screen_class(_sc) = MainActivity,firebase_screen_id(_si) = --,message_device_time(_ndt) = 0,message_name(_nmn) = TestMessage,message_time(_nmt) = --,message_id(_nmid) = ---}]

Comment: Logging event(FE): notification_foreground(_nf), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o) = fcm,firebase_screen_class(_sc) = MainActivity,firebase_screen_id(_si) = --,message_device_time(_ndt) = 0,message_name(_nmn) = TestMessage, message_time(_nmt) = --,message_id(_nmid) = --}]

Comment: 1) that logcat message doesn't say much
2) it's best if you update your original post cause reading code in a comment is hard since there is no proper formatting